# Cannot logon to exchange server with network account anymore

Tags: active-directory, exchange, outlook-web-app

We are receiving the error

```
"The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship"
```

I can login with local administrative account, but performing certain installs require AD access which is erroring out.  IIS was uninstalled yesterday and new certs were also installed, previous to that it was working 100% a-ok.

Comment: Is this a VM by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the workstation from the domain and make it a 'workgroup' box. Then restart and rejoin to the domain. Then restart and see if it works.

Comment: +1 to parent. I bet it has nothing to do with Exchange, and everything to do with the workstation dropping out of the domain. You can also run "netdom reset computername" to do it from the server side, depending on the client error. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788073(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Exchanged had dropped from the domain and we needed to add it back to a bunch of the exchange groups in AD, we had a lot of errors yesterday.  Thanks again :)